# ffmpeg - frames to video using reference timecodes

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video with variable framerate that I decode into single frames using `-vsync passthrough` to avoid duplicate/lost frames. After processing those frames with another application I want to encode them again into an mp4 video that has the **exact same timestamps** as the original video.

My idea is to input the frames plus the original video and use the timecodes of the latter. Is this possible?

This is my current approach:

```
ffmpeg -i input/%d.jpg -vsync 0 -i input.mov  \
    -filter_complex '[0]setpts=PTS[vid1];[vid1]pad=iw*2:ih[vid2];[vid2][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid3]' \
    -map [vid3] -map 1:a \
    -y result.mp4
```

I do a concatenation of both videos side-by-side to see if they are in sync which they are not...

`setpts=PTS` uses the timecodes of the frames so this can not work. However, is there a way of using `PTS` from the second video? Something like `[0]setpts=PTS{1:v:0}`?

Comment: You can do this in two steps. For step 1, see https://superuser.com/q/1126667/ for step 2, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/28086775/

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you very much!!!