# specify timestamps for each video frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an application that reads a VFR video and processes its frames, and then pipe them into ffmpeg for encoding (application cannot do that itself). I know the timestamps of each frame because i have the original video, and could also, for instance, provide them in a file such as a mkv timecode v2 file. How do i set the frame timestamps for each of the incoming raw frames, so that ffmpeg encodes a VFR file? I am using an up to date 5.0.0 build from gyan.dev, on Windows.

command line:

```
-y -f rawvideo -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 25 -pixel_format rgb24 -i pipe: -c:v libx264 sceneVideo.mp4
```

I have tried using `-x264-params tcfile-in=tsFile.txt`, but found out that is a parameter for the x264 command line program, not for using it as a library through ffmpeg, so doesn't work.

Another solution would perhaps be to use `copyts` somehow to instruct ffmpeg to use only the timestamps from the original VFR file during encode (or during a later remux) of the processed video, but how would i do that?

If using another common container such as mkv makes this easier than mp4, that would be ok!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086775) seems to be related, and it appears there is an answer to your inquiry.