# Why is 27000 a magic number for video point/frame description in full numbers

Tags: math, video, calc

One video processing software vendor i work with uses the multiplicator "27000" to describe in and out points of videos in full numbers. I never got out why...

One example:
We want to describe the point [end of the first frame] of a video that has got those properties

- Frames per second: 23.976
- milliseconds per frame: 41,70837504170838
- fps numerator/denominator: 24000/1001

My question is: what makes the number **27000** magical for videos? Or what formula could i use to calculate it...
When multiplying any of the following common video framerates with this magic number, we always get an a value without commas:

Outpoint = (1000/23,97602397602398) * **27000** = 1126125

In Words:

Outpoint= (MillisecondsInASecond/MilliSecondsPerFrame) * 27000

Here a list of common framerates:
[image]

Comment: Long time after asking this, i found further, very good information in the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333542/what-is-video-timescale-timebase-or-timestamp-in-ffmpeg/43337235#43337235

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not really magic. It's about common demoninators...  27000 is just the product of the cubes of the first three prime numbers ...

```
27000 = 2^3 * 3^3 * 5^3
```

That is, 27000 is evenly divisible by a whole slew of numbers...

```
 2
 3
 4  (=2*2)
 5
 6  (=2*3)
 8  (=2*2*2)
 9  (=3*3)
10  (=2*5)
12  (=2*2*3)
15  (=3*5)
```

(notably absent from the list of divisors are primes... `7`, `11`, `13`, ...)

So 27000 is an even multiple of the most common frame rates:

```
24   (=2*2*2*3)
25   (=5*5)
30   (=2*3*5)
50   (=2*5*5)
60   (=2*2*3*5)
120  (=2*2*2*3*5)
```

---

1001 milliseconds / 24 frames

```
( 1001 / 24 ) * 27000
```

can be refactored as

```
1001 * ( 27000 / 24 )
```

the trick is that 27000 (`2^3*3^3*5^3`) is evenly divisible by 24 (`2^3*3`)

```
1001 * ( 2^3*3^3*5^3 ) / (2^3*3)
```

or

```
1001 * (3^2*5^3)
```

---

This trick with 27000 wouldn't work with bizarre frame rates. I don't think anyone does a framerate of 77 frames per second (77=7*11).