# FFprob time stimstempt

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I got this results:

`media_type=video|stream_index=0|key_frame=1|pkt_pts=4004|pkt_pts_time=0.066733|pkt_dts=4004|pkt_dts_time=0.066733|best_effort_timestamp=4004|best_effort_timestamp_time=0.066733|pkt_duration=N/A|pkt_duration_time=N/A|pkt_pos=247781|pkt_size=3110400|width=1920|height=1080|pix_fmt=yuv420p|sample_aspect_ratio=1:1|pict_type=I|coded_picture_number=0|display_picture_number=0|interlaced_frame=0|top_field_first=0|repeat_pict=0|color_range=unknown|color_space=unknown|color_primaries=unknown|color_transfer=unknown|chroma_location=unspecified|tag:lavfi.scene_score=0.441274

media_type=video|stream_index=0|key_frame=1|pkt_pts=9009|pkt_pts_time=0.150150|pkt_dts=9009|pkt_dts_time=0.150150|best_effort_timestamp=9009|best_effort_timestamp_time=0.150150|pkt_duration=N/A|pkt_duration_time=N/A|pkt_pos=278961|pkt_size=3110400|width=1920|height=1080|pix_fmt=yuv420p|sample_aspect_ratio=1:1|pict_type=I|coded_picture_number=0|display_picture_number=0|interlaced_frame=0|top_field_first=0|repeat_pict=0|color_range=unknown|color_space=unknown|color_primaries=unknown|color_transfer=unknown|chroma_location=unspecified|tag:lavfi.scene_score=0.639635

media_type=video|stream_index=0|key_frame=1|pkt_pts=63063|pkt_pts_time=1.051050|pkt_dts=63063|pkt_dts_time=1.051050|best_effort_timestamp=63063|best_effort_timestamp_time=1.051050|pkt_duration=N/A|pkt_duration_time=N/A|pkt_pos=1741936|pkt_size=3110400|width=1920|height=1080|pix_fmt=yuv420p|sample_aspect_ratio=1:1|pict_type=I|coded_picture_number=0|display_picture_number=0|interlaced_frame=0|top_field_first=0|repeat_pict=0|color_range=unknown|color_space=unknown|color_primaries=unknown|color_transfer=unknown|chroma_location=unspecified|tag:lavfi.scene_score=0.477124

media_type=video|stream_index=0|key_frame=1|pkt_pts=142142|pkt_pts_time=2.369033|pkt_dts=142142|pkt_dts_time=2.369033|best_effort_timestamp=142142|best_effort_timestamp_time=2.369033|pkt_duration=N/A|pkt_duration_time=N/A|pkt_pos=5345789|pkt_size=3110400|width=1920|height=1080|pix_fmt=yuv420p|sample_aspect_ratio=1:1|pict_type=I|coded_picture_number=0|display_picture_number=0|interlaced_frame=0|top_field_first=0|repeat_pict=0|color_range=unknown|color_space=unknown|color_primaries=unknown|color_transfer=unknown|chroma_location=unspecified|tag:lavfi.scene_score=0.386543
`

I try to understand that, for my understanding `best_effort_timestamp=4004` represent the boundary of the first shot, but what 4004 represents? milisecond? microsecond?

Comment: Check the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333542/what-is-video-timescale-timebase-or-timestamp-in-ffmpeg/43337235)

Comment: I didn't understand it probably, my video duration is 00:00:10.01, the last best_effort_timestamp is 142142 according to this link calculation it's (142142 * (1/75)) millisecond which is  1895.2266666666667 which is 00:00:01....

Comment: It looks like your time base is `0.066733 / 4004` = `1/60000`, and not `1/75`

Comment: Use `ffprobe` for checking your time base: In Linux: `ffprobe -show_streams your_video_file_name | grep time_base`. In Windows powershell: `./ffprobe -show_streams your_video_file_name | Select-String -Pattern time_base`. What value are you getting?

Comment: Can you please explain it? In the example I added is the millisecond calculate like this: (4004/ (0.066733 / 4004)), (9009/ (0.150150/9009)), (63063/(1.051050/63063)),(142142/(2.369033/142142)) ?

Comment: time_base=1/48000

Comment: It looks like I also don't understand it... I was expecting time_base=1/60000