# Concatenating two.mov files results in identical sized file

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, .mov

I try to concatenate two video files a.mov & b.mov on Win 10 using ffmpeg with the following command:

`ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -vcodec copy -acodec copy c.mov`

There are no errors displayed however when I open the resulting file *c* it has the same length as file *a* with the last frame appering to be a frame of *b*.
File *a* is a longer video, file *b* are credits (couple of seconds) made with ffmpeg from an image file.
Both files have the same aspect ratio, size and framerate.

I try to concatenate two video files a.mov & b.mov on Win 10 using ffmpeg with the following command:

`ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -vcodec copy -acodec copy c.mov`

There are no errors displayed however when I open the resulting file *c* it has the same length as file *a* with the last frame appering to be a frame of *b*.
File *a* is a longer video, file *b* are credits (couple of seconds) made with ffmpeg from an image file.
Both files have the same aspect ratio, size and framerate.

Here the log:

```
  ffmpeg -n -i a.mov -i b.mov 
    ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2
    --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt   libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100   libavcodec     58. 54.100 /
    58. 54.100   libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100   libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100   libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100   libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100   libswresample   3.  5.100 / 
    3.  5.100   libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'a.mov':   Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: qt
        encoder         : Lavf58.62.100   Duration: 00:31:50.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5309 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 4151 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : Core Media Video
          encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
        Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'b.mov':   Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: qt
        encoder         : Lavf58.29.100   Duration: 00:00:10.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 67 kb/s
        Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 64 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
          encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
```

Thank you.

Comment: The inputs must have some different attributes. They must be the same to concat properly. Show the complete output of: `ffmpeg -n -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4`. This command is only to get file info: its does not output a file. It will provide useful info about the inputs and your `ffmpeg` version. This info is required to provide an answer that you can copy and paste. Copy the **complete** log from that command. [Edit] your question and paste the complete log into your question. Ignore the `At least one output file must be specified error` in the log.

Comment: Thanks @llogan, did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problems

Your inputs have some different attributes, but they need to be the same to concatenate:

- The timescales (`30k` vs `11988`) are different. This is probably due to `a.mov` having 30000/1001 proper NTSC frame rate and `b.mov` is 29.97. [`ffprobe` can confirm this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips). The `ffmpeg` output is for "entertainment purposes only" and reports an abbreviated frame rate.
- `a.mov` has audio, but `b.mov` does not.

## To fix it

1. Re-mux `b.mov` and add silent audio:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i b.mov -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=mono -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s24le -video_track_timescale 30k -shortest b2.mov
   ```
2. Then update `list.txt` with the new file (`b2.mov`).
3. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -c copy c.mov
   ```

## Options

- `-f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=mono` makes silent audio with 48000 sample rate and mono channel layout. This matches the sample rate and channel layout of `a.mov`. You can't concatenate an input with audio with an input that has no audio, so this just creates silent filler/dummy audio.
- `-c:v copy` [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the video.
- `-c:a pcm_s24le` chooses the encoder pcm_s24le to create an audio format that matches `a.mov`.
- `-video_track_timescale 30k` sets video timescale to match `a.mov`. See [What is video timescale, timebase, or timestamp in ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43333542/)
- `-shortest` ends the output whenever the shortest input ends. Needed because I did not set a duration for anullsrc (using `-shortest` is easier).

Comment: Thanks again llogan, that worked! I'd be very happy if you would take the time to enlighten me on timescale: I wasn't aware of more than framerate and samplingrate and have no idea what's with that.

Looking at your code:
- `-f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=mono` creates one channel silence
- `-c:v copy` copies the video
- `-c:a pcm_s24le -video_track_timescale 30k -shortest` does something witht the audio stream (I suppose). This bit has something to do with my uper question: Timescale is obviously acting on a video's audio?